# Karate Debug Server Inside Amazon Workspaces

Tags: karate, amazon-workspaces

Using the Karate plugin for VSCode, when attempting to utilize the debug codelens, the process always times out.  Thinking it may be related to the listen port for the debug session not being reachable from the Amazon Workspace.

Has anyone successfully run a debug session inside Amazon Workspace, or any VM?  Are there any special changes you made to get debug working?